# Como resolver um erro de "Catchable fatal error"

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou fazendo uns exercícios de orientação a objeto em PHP e na hora de alterar os dados do banco, me deparo com o seguinte erro

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/Aluno/class/AlunoDAO.php on line 30

Nunca vi ele antes (na minha longa carreira de alguns meses). Alguém sabe me dizer o que significa?

Segue o meu código

Altera-dados.php

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

$alunoDAO = new AlunoDAO();

$nome_imagem = $alunoDAO->buscaFoto($conexao, $id);

$aluno = new Aluno($nome, $cpf, $senha, $nome_imagem);

$alunoDAO->alteraDados($conexao, $aluno, $id);
```

e a minha função na classe `AlunoDAO` (a que está sendo apontado um erro).

```
function alteraDados($conexao, $aluno, $id){
        $senhaMD5 = md5($aluno->getSenha());
        $query = "update alunos set nome = '{$aluno->getNome()}', cpf = '{$aluno->getCpf()}', senha = '{$senhaMD5}', imagem = '{$aluno->getNomeImagem()}' where id = {$id}";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
        return $resultado;
    }
```

Comment: Qual linha é o erro?

Comment: na linha da $query

Comment: Algum dos valores passados é objeto e não uma string, imprima a consulta.

Comment: Como assim, rray?

Comment: faz `echo $query;`

Comment: Aparece os valores todos certos?

Comment: ah, eu tinha feito isso e ele não me retorna nada. fui na página em que aparece o erro, fui no link da  classe e nada.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29868/discussion-between-rray-and-naldson).

Comment: Olha, vou postar uma resposta, coloca ela no teu script, e depois diga o que retornou.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para evitar erros do tipo `Catchable error`, deve-se capturar a exceção lançada, para obter uma informação mais detalhada e controlada do erro, sendo que exceções às vezes disponibilizam até alguns dados sensíveis.

A solução, é instanciar essa função, e chama-la na página em que os erros são retornados, no teu caso, será na página em que crias uma instância das classes.

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    if ( E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR===$errno ) {

        echo "'Catched:' catchable fatal error (". $errstr .")\n";

        return true;    
    }
    return false;
}

set_error_handler('myErrorHandler');
```

Para corrigir o erro, na tua função, faça simplesmente o `fetch`, antes de tentar retornar o valor:

```
function buscaFoto($conexao, $id){
        $query = "select imagem from alunos where id = {$id}";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
        if($resultado){
            $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
            return $linha['imagem'];    
        } else {
            return false;   
        }
    }
```

---

Para mais informações leia:

[Set_Error_Handler - PHP.net](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

[Catching Catchable Errors - SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468487/how-can-i-catch-a-catchable-fatal-error-on-php-type-hinting)

Comment: Era exatamente isso... Muito obrigado!

Comment: Olha, aproveita e guarda a parte que captura as exceções. Costuma a ser útil para criar logs.

Comment: Certo, dica anotada!